# Como fazer a aplicação React rolar para baixo caso o conteúdo não caiba na tela?

Tags: css, react

Achei que fosse natural que, quando o conteúdo do `HTML` não coubesse na tela, o navegador automaticamente possibilitaria a rolagem para facilitar a visualização. No caso a seguir, por exemplo, possuo o componente `Banner` que é renderizado dentro de `AutoAtendimento`:

```
function Banner({children, titulo, className}) {
    return (
            <div className={className}>
                        <div className="Icone">
                            {children}
                        </div>

                        <div className="Conteudo">
                            {titulo}
                        </div>
            </div>
    )
};

function AutoAtendimento() {
    return (
        <div className="Geral">
            <a href="/">
                <Banner className="Cliente" titulo="Sou Cliente"></Banner>
            </a>

            <a href="/">
                <Banner className="Associado" titulo="Sou Associado"></Banner>
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Há pouco, acessei minha aplicação pelo navegador do celular e os Banners não cabiam na tela, por se tratar de um `display: flex;` eles foram organizados em coluna e então quebram o limite vertical da tela. E não consigo rolar para vê-los:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer a aplicação se redimensionar e permitir a rolagem?
A seguir o `CSS` do meu `Banner` e `AutoAtendimento` respectivamente:

```
Banner:
* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

AutoAtendimento:
.Geral {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    margin: 30px;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No CSS do componente `Banner`, você está setando a propriedade `overflow` como `hidden` para **todos** os elementos da sua página, não apenas para os elementos do componente, e isso está impedindo a rolagem. Tente colocar um seletor mais específico para os elementos do componente.

```js
function Banner({children, titulo, className}) {
    return (
            /* Adicionamos uma classe a mais para diferenciar o banner de outras divs */
            <div className={`banner ${className}`}>
                        <div className="Icone">
                            {children}
                        </div>

                        <div className="Conteudo">
                            {titulo}
                        </div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

```css
div.banner {
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```